# Cordova project for both android and windows8

Tags: android, windows, cordova

I would like to use `PhoneGap` - Cordova for developing HTML5 + javascript application that will display sensor data on both win8 and android.

I have a basic question which I didn't understand from my research in the web.
what is the structure of such application? I mean, how to build this cross platform application in one project only?

what I see in phone gap - getting started guide http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides

and many other websites, is that the working mode is to open a project, for example in VS2012, for OS specific. but I want to use this project for win8 and android!

I'll appreciate any help, especially if you have code samples for it and maybe some useful `tools\templates` to open this project.

note: I'm new to HTML5-javascript.

Comment: do you want to develop the android app on Windows?

Comment: yes, I want to develop it on windows, preffering VS2012. is it possible? I havn't understood yet how to work in order to do it in the right way. how to port my application correctly?

Comment: ok, quick google for you: http://androidstudio.tek-tips.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create different projects for each platform if you decide to build the app locally. For example, you need to create an Xcode project in a Mac machine to develop an iOS app. If you are ok to do cloud build, you can check out http://build.phonegap.com where you just need to upload your zipped html/js and css files and it will give u ready to run apps for iOS, Android, Windows mobile, BB etc...

Answer (score 1):

gin,
the structure is you would be coding using jQuery,java script,CSS,resources and your basic HTML.

The HTML API and the CORDOVA's java script will integrate with the native plugins of Phonegap.

We can create our own plugin's,we have a format for it there in the same website.

Comment: I don't understand from your answer: is it a special project for each OS? where I can share code and HTML for cross platform usage?